# where can i get log4j file?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, log4j

I am unable to search it while trying to give the class path,I have imported existing project into my workspace,Now I unable to find out the log4j file,please help me out in this.

Thanks and regards Yogesh k Bendke.

Comment: Hello. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look around and take the [tour], and read through the [help center]. You can also read about [ask] a good question.

Comment: How does your configuration or configuration file looks like?